# Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (401) low level call on HEAD

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am connecting to Elasticsearch cluster using Nest client and I'm getting this issue while adding Index records.

An i missing something?

- Nest v 7.2.1
- Elastic version 7.2.1

**Exception**

```
Failed to create DB Index for Alarm Event.Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (401) low level call on HEAD: /
```

**Audit trail of this API call**

```
[1] BadResponse: Node: http://192.168.0.4:9200/ Exception: PipelineException Took: 00:00:00.0588591
```

```java
var addresses = new[] {
    new Uri("http://192.168.0.4:9200/"),
    new Uri("http://192.168.0.5:9200/"),
    new Uri("http://192.168.0.6:9200/"),
    new Uri("http://192.168.0.7:9200/"),
};
connectionPool = new StaticConnectionPool(addresses);
connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).BasicAuthentication("testuser", "Something_123").DisablePing();
ElasticSearchClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

var indexes = GetAsxIndexes();
var response = ElasticSearchClient.Ping().DebugInformation;
```

Comment: Got a similar problem some months ago. Could you make a string using string in url instead of array[Uri] ?

Comment: The 401 response indicates authentication failed. Are the credenitals correct? Can you ping `http://192.168.0.4:9200/` with those credentials and get a valid response?

Comment: @RussCam yes i did tcpping to private ip from appservice console in azure without any credentials. It gave me connection successfull. is there other way to ping using credentials?

Comment: @sumeet you can use `curl` or PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest` to HTTP(S) ping with credentials

Comment: @RussCam i  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to 
authenticate user [devuser] for REST request 
[/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" 
charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"unable to 
authenticate user [devuser] for REST request 
[/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" 
charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}

I tried hitting internal loadbalancer with powershell invoke webrequest got this error.

Comment: The error message tells you why it fails `"reason":"unable to authenticate user [devuser] for REST request [/]`. The problem is not .NET client specific, but related to authentication failure. Be sure to set up authentication the same on all nodes in the cluster

Comment: @RussCam I am using the ARM template provided ,is there a way to set security to false while deployment through Template? As i am using internal loadbalancer i dont need authentication to connect ES.

Comment: What ARM template are you referring to? I would **strongly** advise against disabling security, but it can be done by changing `elasticsearch.yml` on each node in the cluster, and restarting elasticsearch service/process: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.3/get-started-enable-security.html

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-deploy/7.2/azure-arm-template-getting-started.html 
Recently i have deployed using this template with some extra parameters like xpackPlugins=No .
I am trying to hit using User russ Password Password1234 also tried with bootstrapPassword123 .

Comment: @RussCam the reason i want to disable security at the time of deployment because i cannot ssh to VMs as we are not alowed to use Public IP. for deployment

Comment: Please see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-deploy/7.2/azure-arm-template-security.html. I don't know what parameters have been used for passwords, but if you have ran with the examples on the page you have linked, then the `elastic` user account will have password `adminPassword123`, the value of the `securityAdminPassword` parameter